# SQL query to return all inter related data

Tags: sql

Hi I have one table and one input number. based on which I need an output like mentiones below.

```
TABLE: tab
col1.    col2
113.     568
123.     456
456.     789
789.     102
345.     987
102.      890
890.     null
Input Number: 789
Output:
ouput_col
102
890
456
123
```

Please help me to get a right SQL query or procedure which will give me desired output based on the provided input number. It should be generic query work for data larger than this, which can check backward and forward interlinked data and returns all in a single column as mentioned in output_col. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell us what the logic behind, and what exactly your DBMS is and what you've done so far..?

Comment: And it has to work in 3 different databases huh? Please tag only the actual database you're using, not every one you can think of to try and get more attention to a question

Comment: see, if I have {col1,col2} {123, 456} {456, 789} {789, 870} {870, null}. Output will be like connected data such as {output} {870, 456,123}. It should return backward n forward connectee value. Here I am passing sample input: 789.

Comment: you'd better to edit your question instead of commenting.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan hierarchical/recursive query, kinda like `start with 789 connect by prior col2 = col1`

Comment: @CaiusJard smells like but the respective data doesn't seem to be compatible exactly.

Comment: @caiusjard Your logic seems correct. but can you please provide me detailed query.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, oh , youre right.. it seems more like `start with 789 connect by prior col2 = col1 or prior col1 = col2 where level <=2` or something...

Comment: Yes a recursive cte is the way to go here.